# Gitlab how to Synchronize Gitlab with Git

Tags: git, console, gitlab

I wanna know, if can synchronize the Gitlab project with Git console because all time have to download the project .zip or any program for use like Github client?

Comment: thanks and sorry for my badly english

Comment: Use `git pull` and `git push` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading a .zip of the repository, clone the repository using the git command line tool. For example, to clone the GitLab CE repository using HTTPS:

`git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git`

This will clone the code into `gitlab-ce` directory. Change in to this new directory. From this point forward, use `git pull origin master`, `git push origin master` and other git commands to interact with the remote repository.

For more information about Git basics and using GitLab see http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/README.html

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct if you want to use HTTPS but if you want/prefer to use SSH you can do it this way!

1. Add your public ssh key from github_rsa.pub (which is found in your .ssh folder) to your SSH keys on Gitlab.com
2. Add a `config` file to your .ssh folder that looks like this

   ```
   Host gitlab.com
   RSAAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
   User mygitlabusername
   ```
3. Clone / pull your repository through Git Bash
4. Drag the folder to Github For Windows